# Compare german umlaut in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of german words and I want to eliminate all nouns therefore I look after the first letter being uppercase or lowercase. This works for all words except for the words that begin with an umlaut e.g. `"Äpfel"`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
dictionary = open('dictionary/de.dict', 'r')

for line in dictionary:
    if line[0] == "Ä": # This does not work
        print "Ä found"
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: The problem is not "Ä", it's line[0]. This is just the first byte of a line, but the "Ä" is a two-byte unicode character. You can check this by `print line[0:3]` which gives `Äp` instead of `Äpf`. You have to treat the input as unicode, too. See Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utf8-encoded string `"Ä"` consists of two characters:

```
>>> "Ä"
'\xc3\x84'
```

The unicode string `u"Ä"` is only one.
You have to encode the strings correctly. So if your dictionary is encoded in utf-8 use:

```
import io
dictionary = io.open('dictionary/de.dict', encoding='utf8')
for line in dictionary:
    if line[0].isupper():
        print "Uppercase word", line
```